# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven' - Spring 4.3.7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am tring to configure Spring MVC + Hibernate but when I use this "tx:annotation-driven" on my servlet-context.xml file, I get error descreibed in title.

My servlet-context file is as below.
I am using Spring 4.3.7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd" >

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.nitin.SpringDemo.controller" />

<beans:bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>    
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL" />  
    <beans:property name="username" value="hr" /> 
    <beans:property name="password" value="hr" />  
</beans:bean>  



<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.nitin.SpringDemo.controller</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ServiceInterface" class="com.nitin.SpringDemo.controller.SpringDao">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.nitin.SpringDemo.controller" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

I am new at this i am trying to learn but this configuration is taking lot of time really frustrated now , please if you all can help.

Comment: Try inserting `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` in your `schemaLocation` attribute. That is, replace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd` with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd`

Comment: Heyy Roman It worked !! Thank you So much ! but can you please explain me concept or logic behind it ....

Comment: Great! I've posted an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsi:schemaLocation` should contain *hints* to the XML file processor on where to physically obtain the xsd files that will be used to validate the XML. It is filled

> with pairs of URI references (one for the namespace name, and one for a hint as to the location of a schema document defining names for that namespace name)

Citation comes from https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-loc

So `xsi:schemaLocation` should contain pairs `<schema-URI, physical-location-URI>`. In your case, `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd` is unpaired.

The attribute should look like

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd"
```

(note that I inserted `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` as the penultimate component).